# Caracteres especiales CSV javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, eclipse, csv, codificación

Tengo problemas al descargar un archivo excel, ya que lo genera con problemas de caracteres especiales  por ejemplo "APORTE AÃ‘O VIGENTE" o "LEY NÂº2 ", actualmente recibo los datos desde un base64 (los datos ingresados ahí están correctos y con sus respectives tildes y caracteres especiales)
Ojala me pueda ayudar con aquello.

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
var binaryString = window.atob(data);
var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
    var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    bytes[i] = ascii;
}
return bytes; };
```

y al parecer el problema está en en que lo paso bien desde el servlet pero al tomarlo en el js, se desconfigura con el tema de los caracteres especiales

```
function abrirPlanAnual(){
    var Postulacion = PostulacionGlobal;
    swalCargando("Generando Documento");


var base64  ="";
var decodebase64 = "";
var timer =  $.ajax({ 
    url: "informe_PlanAnualExcel",
    type: "POST",
    data: {idPostulacion:Postulacion},

    success: function(resultado){
        console.log(resultado);

        base64 = window.btoa(resultado);
        decodebase64 = atob(base64);

        console.log(decodebase64);
```

//          return false;

```
        var nameCsv    = "PlanAnual.csv";
        generaDescargableCSV(resultado, nameCsv);
    }
});
$.when(timer)
.done(function(){
    swal.close();
});
```

}

Comment: Entonces lo mas probable es que el problema esté en el `charset` prueba con `windows-1252` que es que el suelen utilizar los programas de office.

Comment: en vez de utf-8 ?

Comment: @JuanPablo exacto

Comment: Lo intenté y no funcionó :c

Comment: Nos ayudaría saber en qué formato está el archivo original.. para eso puedes acudir a posts como [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows). No debería haber problema con el AJAX de jQuery, pero [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings#answer-30106551) podría serte de ayuda a la hora de codificar y descodificar datos en base64.

Comment: Te propongo algo, si estas en windows ve al documento y a la hora de guardarlo asegurate de darle a guardar como: y entonces en las opciones debajo tendrás una opción de códificación del documento, deberas usar UTF-8, de esta manera el nuevo archivo que haz guardado tendrá una codificación correcta, es decir, el problema puede que no sea el servidor o como decodificas el archivo, si no que la codificación del archivo en sí es diferente. A mi me pasaba que en ciertos PCs al abrir un archivo aparecian caracteres extraños, eso era porque estaba guardandolos con una codificacion no adecuada.

Comment: Mas extraño aún es que esos caracteres extraños no aparecian en el documento cuando lo abria desde mi misma computadora, pero si cuando lo abria en otra u otras, así que podemos pensar en esa simple opción, si ello no funciona habrá que buscar mas a fondo cual es el problema...

Comment: @Riven El archivo está generado en base64, efectivamente al decodificar el base por alguna pagina, tiene los caracteres como corresponde... pero al tomarlo desde el servlet y pasarlo a js, ya vienen los caracteres raros, y tambien probé lo de guardarlo como UTF-8 desde el excel y funcionó, cuando ejecuto el tomcat en linux, me descarga sin ningun problema el archivo (yo lo convierto a csv)

Comment: Osea que lo que dije soluciono tu problema??

Comment: @Riven o sea, es una configuracion desde el excel, pero no aplica si quiero descargarlo en otro pc, y con lo de linux, nunca tuve problemas de caracteres especiales, solo con windows.

Answer (score 1):

este tipo de errores se dan cuando la codificación de inicio a fin es diferente en algún punto, puedes probar con un archivo excel nuevo, **Guardar como** > Herramientas > Opciones web > Codificación y selecciones (Unicode UTF-8 o el que tengas)
Hecho esto vuelves a comprobar que al convertir a base 64 sigas el estándar de codificación (UTF-8 o el que tengas):

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}

utf8_to_b64('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="

b64_to_utf8('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
```

para cuando lo descargues se mantenga.
[Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_codificando_y_decodificando)

Answer (score 1):

El problema, al parecer, es que estas recibiendo la data en formato Unicode/UTF-16 que en que se almacenan los datos en excel. Pero cuando utilizas `btoa` o `atob` se esta interpretando como UTF-8.

Un ejemplo:

```js
var data = new Uint16Array([0x41, 0xD1, 0x4F]);
var decoder = new TextDecoder('UTF-16'); // Si no se especifica por defecto es UTF-8
console.log(decoder.decode(data));
```

Como veras, cuando corres el snippet, los caracteres latinos (con tilde) se interpretan (e imprimen) de forma correcta.

Comment: Pruebo y te comento

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te sea de utilidad por lo que he visto la función escape te permite escapar caracteres especiales, te dejo la documentación por si te sirve de utilidad
[info escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

```js
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}
var comillas =['APORTE AÃ‘O VIGENTE','LEY NÂº2']

console.log(comillas[0] +'\t===>\t'+ utf8_to_b64(comillas[0]));
console.log(comillas[1] +'\t\t===>\t'+ utf8_to_b64(comillas[1]));
console.log(utf8_to_b64(comillas[0])+'\t===>\t'+ 
b64_to_utf8(utf8_to_b64(comillas[0])));
console.log(utf8_to_b64(comillas[1])+'\t\t\t===>\t'+  
b64_to_utf8(utf8_to_b64(comillas[1])));
```

Comment: No me funcionó, me cambió el tipo de caracter extraño solamente, pero siguen estando con problemas :C